# What are the defining features of Capitalism?

Tags: reference-request, capitalism, schools-of-thought

What are the **necessary and sufficient** conditions for an economic system (or mode of production) to be classified as "Capitalism"?

Is it markets? Is it for-profit corporations? Is it limited liability companies? Is it workers selling their labour to capitalists/employees? Is it freedom to set up companies? Is it a low degree of government productive activity? Is it a subset of these or other elements?

I imagine the answer would depend on a particular schools of thought, so in principle I would expect different answers.

*Disclaimer 1*: this question is not requesting **opinions** about what capitalism is, it is not, it should be, it should be not, but authoritative answers, with proper references.

*Disclaimer 2*: for those voting to close this as *too-broad*, [I asked on meta](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/is-this-question-on-topic) whether this question was on-topic, and (albeit not a popular post) it seems people agreed it was.

Comment: I don't think such references exist (unless you mean references to someone else's opinion of which there are plenty) but you should add the "reference request" tag.

Comment: The older word is "capitalist" which just describes the owners of productive capital. The word capitalism was used first by early socialists and was used to describe a system in which capitalists, not workers, were allowed to own productive capital. I think today capitalism is an ill defined word and different people use it to describe different things. In it's original meaning it has nothing to do with free markets, just property rights to the "means of production".

Comment: formally defining capitalism xd *dabs furiously* we anthropology now boyz

Comment: @Tobias That sounds like an answer, If you could add some references too, it would be great.

Comment: I wanted to write that economists never use the word capitalism, preferring to stick to better-defined terms. But then I remembered that Friedman wrote a whole book called Capitalism and Freedom.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Yes, it remains a [popular topic](http://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=capitalism&acc=on&wc=on&fc=off&group=none), and it inserts neatly in a whole category of [JEL codes](https://www.aeaweb.org/econlit/jelCodes.php?view=jel#P).

Comment: I make this a comment and not an answer specifically because it is an opinion. However, I am curious if my opinion aligns with others' opinions. I have always thought of this in terms of state vs. private ownership, degree of regulation, and wealth redistribution mechanisms. Anyone else want to add? I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: I'm surprised this question was closed as too broad. It seems the word "capitalism" is what's used too broadly, to mean any free market economy…

Answer (score 0):

In [this article](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0003122412468882), sociologist Erik Olin Wright provides a definition of 
capitalism (from a socialist tradition):

> Many people equate capitalism with the idea of a market economy. Capitalism is not simply an economy in which markets play a central role in 
>   coordinating economic activity; it is a specific kind of  market  economy,  one  in  which  workers  do  not own and control the firms in which they work, capital  is  privately  owned  and  allocated  to  alternative purposes  on  the  basis  of  private  economic  returns  (or, equivalently, on the basis of private profit-making),  and  labor  is  allocated  to  economic  activities through labor markets.

Comment: This definition still doesn't seem to get to the essence of capitalism, which seems to be [considering money a means of production](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/11358/4101).